# Image keeps changing filetype on upload

Tags: laravel, vue.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, inertiajs

When trying to upload an image, the mimetype keeps changing from imaage/jpg to application/octet-stream, I have no clue why because I could upload the same image 5 times and each time could give a different mimetype, is there a way to force laravel or vue.js to make application/octet-stream into an image type?
here is my HTML

```
<input type="file" id="banner" name="filename">
```

Here is my vue.js post request using inertia.js

```
this.$inertia.post(route('user.edit', this.user.id), object,{
            onSuccess: () => {
                this.sweetAlertSuccess(attribute); // fire success message
                axios.get('/user/' + this.user.id).then(resp => {
                    resp.data.media.forEach(el => {
                        if(el.collection_name === 'banner'){
                            this.banner = el.original_url;
                        }
                        if(el.collection_name === 'avatar'){
                            this.avatar = el.original_url;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your server is not accepting the weight of the images and by default it changes the mime type, modify the following variables in the `php.ini`

(to locate this file check the `phpinfo();` function)

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

```
upload_max_filesize = 60M
post_max_size = 60M
```

The value by default is in 2M, set this value according to yours need, after modifying `php.ini` file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use the new configuration.

May be need any of this commands:

```
service apache2 restart
service httpd restart
service php-fpm restart
```